# Align an array based on another array using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, algorithm, data-structures

Given Header array and make all other arrays into same format of header array:

```
HEADER     ["", "", "a", "b", "", "c", "d","",""]
1.           ["", "", "1", "2", "", "3", "4"]     ==== CORRECT FORMAT
2.           ["1","2","", "3", "4","",""]         ==== WRONG FORMAT
3.           ["", "", "", "", "1", "2", "", "3", "4"] = WRONG FORMAT

Output array :
1.           ["", "", "1", "2", "", "3", "4"]
2.           ["", "", "1", "2", "", "3", "4"]
3.           ["", "", "1", "2", "", "3", "4"]
```

Header and input array length is same. But the output array length must be till the last of element of the header array.

I am unable to fix all types of inputs with below algorithm:

```
  alignArray(arr1, arr2) {
    let arr3 = [];
    let arr4 = _.compact(arr2);
    let count = 0;
    _.map(arr1, function (num, index) {
      if (_.isString(num) && !(_.isEmpty(num))) {
        if (arr4[count])
          arr3.push(arr4[count]);
        else
          arr3.push("");
        count++;
      } else {
        arr3.push("");
      }
    });
    return arr3;
  }
```

Comment: Please provide a verifiable example where your code fails. As far as I can tell, your code does not compile (as JavaScript). Please also clarify what "the places of the elements in input array depends on base array" means.

Comment: Actually it is underscore.js, I am unable to come up with failed example as this program is middle of my large program which is csv alignment. I have a CSV Alignment issue where I am trying based on the header. Lets say header is in correct format, I want all the remaining the rows should be aligned to the Header.  Lets say if the header is having spaces in the starting that does not mean there should not be any elements in the input array. 
**
BASE  = ["", "", "", "", "A", "B", "C", "D"]
INPUT  = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "", "", "6"]
O/P: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "", "6", ""]
**

Comment: Is the example you commented, `** BASE = ["", "", "", "", "A", "B", "C", "D"] INPUT = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "", "", "6"] O/P: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "", "6", ""] **` a failure or expected result? If it's a failure, what is the expected result?

Comment: @גלעדברקן apologies for the confusion, updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to treat the first input array like a queue, dequeueing items whenever `b` has a value. Based on your update, I've trimmed off empty strings at the end of the output array.

```js
const alignArray = (a, b) => {
  a = a.filter(e => e);
  b = b.map(e => e === "" ? e : a.shift() || "");
  let idx = b.length - 1;
  
  for (; idx >= 0 && b[idx] === ""; idx--);
    
  return b.slice(0, idx + 1);
};

const header = ["", "", "a", "b", "", "c", "d", "", ""];
const rows = [
  ["", "", "1", "2", "", "3", "4", "", ""],
  ["1","2","", "3", "4","",""],
  ["", "", "", "", "1", "2", "", "3", "4"]
];

rows.forEach(e => console.log(alignArray(e, header)));
```